# unable to get facebook permissions on android

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have created a test user and tried logging in to the app but I just got public_profile permissions and not user_friends,user_Likes and user_birthday.Also this is a sample hellofacebook app.
I have added :

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
                    this,
                    Arrays.asList("user_friends","email", "user_birthday","users_likes"));
```

How can I get the above permissions to work in development mode before release?I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

COde :

```
package com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView;
import com.facebook.share.ShareApi;
import com.facebook.share.Sharer;
import com.facebook.share.internal.ShareInternalUtility;
import com.facebook.share.model.SharePhoto;
import com.facebook.share.model.SharePhotoContent;
import com.facebook.share.model.ShareLinkContent;
import com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;

public class HelloFacebookSampleActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String PERMISSION = "publish_actions";
    private static final Location SEATTLE_LOCATION = new Location("") {
        {
            setLatitude(47.6097);
            setLongitude(-122.3331);
        }
    };

    private final String PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY =
            "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook:PendingAction";

    private Button postStatusUpdateButton;
    private Button postPhotoButton;
    private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
    private TextView greeting;
    private PendingAction pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
    private boolean canPresentShareDialog;
    private boolean canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;
    private ShareDialog shareDialog;
    private FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> shareCallback = new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("HelloFacebook", "Canceled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d("HelloFacebook", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
            String title = getString(R.string.error);
            String alertMessage = error.getMessage();
            showResult(title, alertMessage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
            Log.d("HelloFacebook", "Success!");
            if (result.getPostId() != null) {
                String title = getString(R.string.success);
                String id = result.getPostId();
                String alertMessage = getString(R.string.successfully_posted_post, id);
                showResult(title, alertMessage);
            }
        }

        private void showResult(String title, String alertMessage) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(HelloFacebookSampleActivity.this)
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setMessage(alertMessage)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                    .show();
        }
    };

    private enum PendingAction {
        NONE,
        POST_PHOTO,
        POST_STATUS_UPDATE
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        handlePendingAction();
                        updateUI();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE) {
                            showAlert();
                            pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
                        }
                        updateUI();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE
                                && exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException) {
                            showAlert();
                            pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
                        }
                        updateUI();
                    }

                    private void showAlert() {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(HelloFacebookSampleActivity.this)
                                .setTitle(R.string.cancelled)
                                .setMessage(R.string.permission_not_granted)
                                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        shareDialog.registerCallback(
                callbackManager,
                shareCallback);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String name = savedInstanceState.getString(PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY);
            pendingAction = PendingAction.valueOf(name);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
                updateUI();
                // It's possible that we were waiting for Profile to be populated in order to
                // post a status update.
                handlePendingAction();
            }
        };

        profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
        greeting = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greeting);

        postStatusUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postStatusUpdateButton);
        postStatusUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickPostStatusUpdate();
            }
        });

        postPhotoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postPhotoButton);
        postPhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickPostPhoto();
            }
        });

        // Can we present the share dialog for regular links?
        canPresentShareDialog = ShareDialog.canShow(
                ShareLinkContent.class);

        // Can we present the share dialog for photos?
        canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos = ShareDialog.canShow(
                SharePhotoContent.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Call the 'activateApp' method to log an app event for use in analytics and advertising
        // reporting.  Do so in the onResume methods of the primary Activities that an app may be
        // launched into.
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

        updateUI();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putString(PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY, pendingAction.name());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Call the 'deactivateApp' method to log an app event for use in analytics and advertising
        // reporting.  Do so in the onPause methods of the primary Activities that an app may be
        // launched into.
        AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        profileTracker.stopTracking();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        boolean enableButtons = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null;

        postStatusUpdateButton.setEnabled(enableButtons || canPresentShareDialog);
        postPhotoButton.setEnabled(enableButtons || canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos);

        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        if (enableButtons && profile != null) {
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(profile.getId());
            greeting.setText(getString(R.string.hello_user, profile.getFirstName()));
        } else {
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(null);
            greeting.setText(null);
        }
    }

    private void handlePendingAction() {
        PendingAction previouslyPendingAction = pendingAction;
        // These actions may re-set pendingAction if they are still pending, but we assume they
        // will succeed.
        pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;

        switch (previouslyPendingAction) {
            case NONE:
                break;
            case POST_PHOTO:
                postPhoto();
                break;
            case POST_STATUS_UPDATE:
                postStatusUpdate();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void onClickPostStatusUpdate() {
        performPublish(PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE, canPresentShareDialog);
    }

    private void postStatusUpdate() {
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
                .setContentDescription(
                        "The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/docs/android"))
                .build();
        if (canPresentShareDialog) {
            shareDialog.show(linkContent);
        } else if (profile != null && hasPublishPermission()) {
            ShareApi.share(linkContent, shareCallback);
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
        }
    }

    private void onClickPostPhoto() {
        performPublish(PendingAction.POST_PHOTO, canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos);
    }

    private void postPhoto() {
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
        SharePhoto sharePhoto = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image).build();
        ArrayList<SharePhoto> photos = new ArrayList<>();
        photos.add(sharePhoto);

        SharePhotoContent sharePhotoContent =
                new SharePhotoContent.Builder().setPhotos(photos).build();
        if (canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos) {
            shareDialog.show(sharePhotoContent);
        } else if (hasPublishPermission()) {
            ShareApi.share(sharePhotoContent, shareCallback);
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_PHOTO;
        }
    }

    private boolean hasPublishPermission() {
        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        return accessToken != null && accessToken.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
    }

    private void performPublish(PendingAction action, boolean allowNoToken) {
        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if (accessToken != null) {
            pendingAction = action;
            if (hasPublishPermission()) {
                // We can do the action right away.
                handlePendingAction();
                return;
            } else {
                // We need to get new permissions, then complete the action when we get called back.
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(
                        this,
                        Arrays.asList(PERMISSION));



                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
                        this,
                        Arrays.asList("user_friends","email", "user_birthday","users_likes"));
                return;
            }
        }

        if (allowNoToken) {
            pendingAction = action;
            handlePendingAction();
        }
    }
}
```

layout_xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="#FFF"
        >
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:background="#FFF"
                  android:id="@+id/main_ui_container">
        <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            facebook:confirm_logout="false"
            facebook:tooltip_mode="never_display"
            />
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/greeting"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#333"
                    android:textSize="18sp"/>
            <com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView
                    android:id="@+id/profilePicture"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    facebook:preset_size="normal"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/postStatusUpdateButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Post Status Update"
                    />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/postPhotoButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Post Photo"
                    />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HelloFacebook app uses the login button, you should add the read permissions there, first add an id to the LoginButton in the layout.xml.

Then around here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/HelloFacebookSample/src/com/facebook/samples/hellofacebook/HelloFacebookSampleActivity.java#L185

Add a snippet like:

```
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "user_birthday");
```

Make sure you unTos the app first from https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications if you've logged in before, because the app will think that the user denied those permissions and won't ask again.

Comment: HOw can I use LoginManager to get the same permissions?

Comment: LoginButton uses LoginManager under the hood. So  LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions method also works. You should do it before you ask for publish permissions though, and make sure the user has unTos'ed the app as I described before.

Comment: So,  


                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
                        this,
                        Arrays.asList("user_friends","email", "user_birthday","users_likes"));
                return;                                                                                                                                           LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(
                        this,
                        Arrays.asList(PERMISSION));

Comment: Error: Unreachable statement.

Comment: It's because of the return statement.

Comment: Yeah got it. Thanks. Btw ,how can a test user like a page or create one.Basically how can I test "user_likes" with test users?

Comment: Create your test user, in your apps settings, Roles, Test Users or use an existing one for your app. Click the edit button near the test user, you can login as that user to create a page. You have other options in that pulldown menu. Please create new top level questions, so they're discoverable by others.

Comment: Thanks Gokhan.But,I was unable to create a test page using test_user.I keep getting error.I will post a new Q with the error.PLease look into it.THanks again for your help.

Comment: Please check this out thanks :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648831/how-can-facebook-test-user-create-a-page

Comment: Please check this out :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693951/facebook-v4-crashing-after-login-in-android